# Whenever I try to navigate to a link, the entire page moves, not the material in the scrolling div

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to have a scrolling Div with my main content. At the top of that content is my Table of Contents that links to the other material in the scrolling Div. I found some code that automates the ToC, however I can not for the life of me figure out how to get only the scrolling Div to move when I attempt to navigate. Ultimately, I intend to have the ToC navigate to the FAQ question and add a button that appears later to bring the user back to the top.

Is there a technique or Tutorial somewhere that will allow me to do what I want to do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toc").append('<br>')
  $("h3").each(function(i) {
    var current = $(this);
    current.attr("id", "title" + i);

    $("#toc").append("<p><a id='link" + i + "' href='#title" + i + "' title='" + current.attr("tagName") + "'>" + current.html() + "</a></p>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="contentarea">
  <div class="title" id="newstitle">
    <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="toc"></div>
  <div class="article" id="content">
    <h3>How does sponsorship work at this event?</h3>
    <p>Sponsorship is available to businesses who wish to contribute to the success of the event. If you or your business wish to become a sponsor for HonorCon 2017, please contact the convention chair committee at <a target="_blank" href="mailto:conchair2@gmail.com">conchair2@gmail.com</a>.
      Our sponsors receive the most benefit from their donations, as only sponsors are advertised on our website as compared to the space for sale in our program. There are 3 levels of sponsorship available:</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>What are the convention space rules?/Do you have a harrassment policy?</h3>
    <p>The staff of HonorCon wishes to ensure a safe and comfortable environment for all attendees. We encourage you to come to have a good time and to be whomever you wish to be. We believe that conventions should be safe spaces to enjoy and explore science
      fiction, cosplay, and gaming. If at any time you feel that your safety or the safety of others is in jeopardy, please contact Convention Security immediately (Shore Patrol), who will then contact the Police and Hotel Security as required. To that
      end, however, certain forms of behavior have been deemed inappropriate by the convention committee.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Who are those guys in the yellow berets and brassards?</h3>
    <p>Both HonorCon and MantiCon are put on by the Royal Manticoran Navy: the Official Honor Harrington Association. Because the setting in the Honor Harrington series is primarily based on a futuristic space navy, it stands to reason that our convention's
      security and all-around help-force would be called "Shore Patrol" in honor of the naval military police's peace-keeping function when ships come into port. HonorCon's Shore Patrol performs security functions for the convention in cooperation with
      the venue's management and should be the go-to people should you have any concerns or feel in need of help of any kind.If at ay time you feel that your safety or the safety of others is in jeopardy, please contact Shore Patrol emmediately.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Where is the event?</h3>
    <div>
      <p>HonorCon 2017 will be held in the luxurious Hilton North Raleigh/Midtown. The address is:</p>
      <br>
      <p>3415 Wake Forest Road</p>
      <p>Raleigh, North Carolina 27609-7330</p>
      <p>USA</p>
      <p>Telephone: 1(919)872-2323</p>
      <p>Fax: 1(919)876-0890</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>My question isn't here, who do I contact for an answer?</h3>
    <p>If we've overlooked something that you are dying to know or an explanation is unclear, you have three possible courses of action. The first is to go to the "<a target="_self" href="contact.html">Contact Us!</a>" page of this website and click on the
      picture of the person whose department best fits the category of your question. This will help set up and address an e-mail to the person most likely to be able to answer your question on the staff. If you are unable to find an appropriate representative
      who seems like they can meet your needs send an e-mail to <a target="_blank" href="mailto:conchair2@gmail.com">conchair2@gmail.com</a>. And finally, if time is of the essence, feel free to message us on Facebook using Facebook messenger. Click
      <a
        target="_self" href="https://www.facebook.com/HonorCon/">here</a> to go to our Facebook page!</p>
  </div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So what is the problem? What errors are you getting and what have you tried? I also recommend you only display the relevant source rather than just dumping it into your question expecting people to read through to find the part relevant to your question.

Comment: The problem is that what I have is probably working according to its design. I can't get the Table of Contents to only scroll within the scroll box. When I attempt to navigate, it moves the entire page around which makes it look horrible. I can't find a technique that works as yet to solve the problem.

Comment: Edited the post as per first comment. The JS Script does what it is supposed to do. It is not malfunctioning per se. I just don't know how to modify it to meet my requirements.

Comment: Do you have CSS for this page?

Comment: You need to both add your CSS and be more specific what _"within the scroll box"_ mean, and where is that scroll box?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean that when user clicks on a link, the page should scroll instead of jumping to the relevant paragraph.

Here is the solution for that:

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

refer article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/